# lua check for table on stack from c api

Tags: c, lua

I could find a lot of information how to retrieve the values of the table in lua from the stack in C api, however I am experiencing a bit different problem - when my function is called without the table passed my programs crushes without any warning.

Which leads me to the following question, is there any way of checking the existence of table on the stack from C api? Similar to lua_checkstring(L, )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself during the investigation of the C lua API.

The proper function to use to investigate the stack are the is function, so instead of Lua_checkstring I should be using lua_isstring(L, offset). The alternative for lua_istable exists.

As suggested by siffiejoe it is also possible to do with luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE), the difference being the check type will rise an error in the parser.

Comment: In case you want to raise an error if no table is passed to a function, you can also use [`luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_checktype).

Comment: thanks for the comment! it sounds really useful as well!